# updating Primary key value with value '02' not saving

Tags: mysql

When i update primary column with value '02' its saving to only 2. But it should be saved as 02.

When i run the following sql am not getting any error and saving successfully. But the value is not updating. Its not accepting any values that starts with '0'.

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `id` = '02' WHERE `id` =2 ;
```

Comment: what is the data type of ID field? INTEGER???

Comment: I am not mysql expert, but what is a datatype of your [id] column. From where close i can conclude that it is integer. 02 will be parsed to 2 then

Answer (score 1):

Declare your id column as [Zerofill](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html). The column declared with zerofill can be used to display values with leading zeros But this means not that it actually store the leading zeros. It does not store the leading zeros but used to display values with leading zeros

You can modify existing column.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY `id` INT(11) ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate respone. But its saving the value '02' as '00000000002' and '0222' as '00000000222'. As we defined int(11), the remaining length is filling with 0's. I need exact the value. (02,0222)

Comment: Define it as VARCHAR. 02 and 2 are the same int values!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the data type of the `id` column from a numeric data type to `VARCHAR` or similar to save the leading zero. Otherwise, 02 is the same number as 2 , 002, 0002, 00002 .. etc.